# how can I clear input field in react after click submit?

Tags: reactjs, form-submit, reset, onsubmit

This is the section of my footer which have the form,
I need this form to reset or clear the inputs after submitting,
I tried to add event.target.reset(); in the handleSubmit(event){} but not worked,
and I tried to add the variables to be equal '' empty but nothing happened.

this is the handleSubmit

```
    async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      phone: this.state.number,
      subject:this.state.subject,
      text: this.state.message,
    };
    const url = "http://localhost:3030/send-email";
    const result = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    console.log(result);
    
  }
```

and this is the form

```
 <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Grid container>
                  <Grid className={classes.gridOne} item xs={12}>
                    <TextField
                      className={classes.textArea}
                      fullWidth
                      id="name"
                      label="Name"
                      name="name"
                      type="text"
                      value={this.state.name}
                      onChange={this.handleChangeName}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid
                    item
                    lg={6}
                    md={12}
                    sm={12}
                    xs={12}
                    className={classes.gridTwo}
                  >
                    <TextField
                      className={classes.textArea}
                      fullWidth
                      id="email"
                      label="E-mail"
                      name="email"
                      type="email"
                      value={this.state.email}
                      onChange={this.handleChangeEmail}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid
                    item
                    lg={6}
                    md={12}
                    sm={12}
                    xs={12}
                    className={classes.gridThree}
                  >
                    <TextField
                      className={classes.textArea}
                      fullWidth
                      id="phone"
                      label="Phone"
                      name="number"
                      type="number"
                      value={this.state.number}
                      onChange={this.handleChangeNumber}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.gridFour}>
                  <TextField
                      className={classes.textArea}
                      fullWidth
                      id="subject"
                      label="Subject"
                      name="subject"
                      type="text"
                      value={this.state.subject}
                      onChange={this.handleChangeSubject}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.gridFour}>
                    <TextField
                      name="message"
                      id="message"
                      label="Message"
                      placeholder="Placeholder"
                      rows={4}
                      multiline
                      fullWidth
                      className={classes.textArea}
                      value={this.state.message}
                      onChange={this.handleChangeMessage}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                 
                  <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <Button
                      type="submit"
                      id="test"
                      className={classes.button}
                      variant="outlined"
                      
                    >
                      Send Message
                    </Button>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </form>
```

and this is the all code

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
    import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
    import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
    import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
    import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
    import { Link } from "@material-ui/core";
    import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
    
   
    class Footer extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { name: "" };
        this.state = { email: "" };
        this.state = { number: "" };
        this.state = { message: "" };
        this.state = { subject: "" };
        
    
        this.handleChangeName = this.handleChangeName.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeEmail = this.handleChangeEmail.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeNumber = this.handleChangeNumber.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeMessage = this.handleChangeMessage.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeSubject = this.handleChangeSubject.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }
      handleChangeName(event) {
        this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
      }
      handleChangeEmail(event) {
        this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
      }
      handleChangeNumber(event) {
        this.setState({ number: event.target.value });
      }
      handleChangeMessage(event) {
        this.setState({ message: event.target.value });
      }
      handleChangeSubject(event) {
        this.setState({ subject: event.target.value });
      }
    
    
      async handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        const data = {
          name: this.state.name,
          email: this.state.email,
          phone: this.state.number,
          subject:this.state.subject,
          text: this.state.message,
        };
        const url = "http://localhost:3030/send-email";
        const result = await fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        });
        console.log(result);
        
      }
    
      state = {};
      render() {
        // const send = (props) => {
        //     sendMail(this.state.name, this.state.email, this.state.number,this.state.message);
        // };
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
          <div className={classes.backG}>
            <Container className={classes.padContainer}>
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item lg={4} md={4} sm={12} xs={12}></Grid>
        
                <Grid item lg={8} md={8} sm={12} xs={12}>
                  <Typography className={classes.titleTwo}>
                    Interested in doing a project together? Email me
                  </Typography>
                  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <Grid container>
                      <Grid className={classes.gridOne} item xs={12}>
                        <TextField
                          className={classes.textArea}
                          fullWidth
                          id="name"
                          label="Name"
                          name="name"
                          type="text"
                          value={this.state.name}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeName}
                        />
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid
                        item
                        lg={6}
                        md={12}
                        sm={12}
                        xs={12}
                        className={classes.gridTwo}
                      >
                        <TextField
                          className={classes.textArea}
                          fullWidth
                          id="email"
                          label="E-mail"
                          name="email"
                          type="email"
                          value={this.state.email}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeEmail}
                        />
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid
                        item
                        lg={6}
                        md={12}
                        sm={12}
                        xs={12}
                        className={classes.gridThree}
                      >
                        <TextField
                          className={classes.textArea}
                          fullWidth
                          id="phone"
                          label="Phone"
                          name="number"
                          type="number"
                          value={this.state.number}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeNumber}
                        />
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.gridFour}>
                      <TextField
                          className={classes.textArea}
                          fullWidth
                          id="subject"
                          label="Subject"
                          name="subject"
                          type="text"
                          value={this.state.subject}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeSubject}
                        />
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.gridFour}>
                        <TextField
                          name="message"
                          id="message"
                          label="Message"
                          placeholder="Placeholder"
                          rows={4}
                          multiline
                          fullWidth
                          className={classes.textArea}
                          value={this.state.message}
                          onChange={this.handleChangeMessage}
                        />
                      </Grid>
                     
                      <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <Button
                          type="submit"
                          id="test"
                          className={classes.button}
                          variant="outlined"
                          
                        >
                          Send Message
                        </Button>
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </form>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Container>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default withStyles(useStyles)(Footer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be initializing the state as shown below:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      number: "",
      message: "",
      subject: ""
    }
```

Then you just need to reset the state, since inputs are controlled they will also update. Try:

```
this.setState({
  name: '',
  email: '',
  phone: '',
  subject: '',
  text: ''
});
```

Comment: `this.state = { name: "" }` this seems wrong, it should be `this.state = { name: "", email: "", number: ""  }` and so on. If it doesn't work please create a [mcve] in codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

I think good solution is to create function in your class component to reset state and then after fetch and positive result you can reset the fields, otherwise you can throw some message with error, so

```
class Footer extends Component {
   ...
   function resetState () {
      this.setState({
      name: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
      subject: '',
      text: ''
   });
}
```

and then in your handleSubmit fucntion you can do it like this:

```
async handleSubmit(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
    
   const data = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      phone: this.state.number,
      subject:this.state.subject,
      text: this.state.message,
    };
   const url = "http://localhost:3030/send-email";
   const result = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      });
      console.log(result);

      if (result === "OK") {
         this.resetState();
      }
      else { 
         alert("Some error occurred");
      }
   }
```

Comment: I tried to make this but still not working

Comment: Maybe change your

`this.state = { name: "" };
        this.state = { email: "" };
        this.state = { number: "" };
        this.state = { message: "" };
        this.state = { subject: "" };`
into:
`this.state = {
     name: "",
     email: "",
     number: "" ,
     message: "",
     subject: "" 
};`

Answer (score 0):

For setting the form empty after submission, just change the state to an empty string or simply "". your handleSubmit function should look like

```
async handleSubmit(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
 
     const data = {
       name: this.state.name,
       email: this.state.email,
       phone: this.state.number,
       subject:this.state.subject,
       text: this.state.message,
     };
     const url = "http://localhost:3030/send-email";
     const result = await fetch(url, {
       method: "POST",
       body: JSON.stringify(data),
       headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
       },
     });
     console.log(result);
     this.setState({
          name: "",
          email: "",
          phone: "",
          subject: "",
          text: "",
     })
     
   }
```

Comment: How is this adding anything more than the two existing answers?

Comment: I make this but not working, nothing happened